# Trying to sort collection by last entry

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Hy I am new to android and fire store
I am trying to get data from a collection by last entry first

if some have any advice on how am I supose to do that it will be very helpful

```
    mFireStore.collection(Constans.BOARDS)
        //.whereArrayContains(Constans.ASSIGNED_TO, getCurrentUid())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            document ->
            Log.e("getBoardsList",document.documents.toString()+"inside addOnSuccessListener")
            Log.e("getBoardsList","inside addOnSuccessListener")

            Constans.BOARDS_CHATS_LIST = ArrayList()

            for (i in document.documents){
                val board = i.toObject(Board::class.java)!!
                for (j in board.assinedTo) {
                    if (getCurrentUid() == j) {
                        board.documentId = i.id
                        Log.e("documentId", "${i.id}")
                        Constans.BOARDS_CHATS_LIST.add(board)
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("getBoardsList","${Constans.BOARDS_CHATS_LIST.size.toString()}")
            //activity.hideProgressDialog()

        }.addOnFailureListener {
            e ->
            //activity.hideProgressDialog()
            Log.e("getBoardsList","Error while creating the board"+"inside addOnFailureListener",e)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore doesn't maintain a time-based ordering of any documents.  If you want to know what the "last" document is, you'll have to put some sort of [timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) in a field in each document, then [order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) the query by that field.  Otherwise, what you're trying to do is impossible.